Questions about the transpose of gradient of the image and corresponding Fourier transformation
I have a question about the transpose of the gradient like $$\nabla_{x}^{\tau}I$$ where $I$ is the image data. Is $\nabla_{x}^{\tau}I=\nabla_{y}I$ ?
And another problem is related to $\nabla_{x}^{\tau}\nabla_{x}I$,is it equal to Laplace operator in the $x$ direction of image $I$?
Finally, how to derive $\mathcal{F}(\nabla_{x}^{\tau}\nabla_{x}I)=\mathcal{F}(\nabla_{x})^{*}\mathcal{F}(\nabla_{x})\mathcal{F}(I)$, where $\mathcal{F}(.)$ is the Fourier transformation, and $\mathcal{F}(\nabla_{x})^{*}$ is conjugate to $\mathcal{F}(\nabla_{x})$.
Thanks!
